# Google Cloud Dataflow + Java 8 vs Java 11: same pipeline, different CPU utilization on workers

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Beam 2.25.0 pipeline that gets some data, generates a bunch more data (does a fanout), repartitions the new data, and runs computations on that generated data in parallel. The machines I specify for the job are n1-highmem-4 and I specify 40 workers max.

It works fine under Java 8: all workers provided to the job are fully utilized (>90% CPU). Throughput is 40 elements/s.

[image: pipeline running in java8]

When I recompile and re-run the pipeline to use Java 11, the same number of workers are provided to the job, but they only reach 30% CPU utilization, and throughput is less, under 18/s.

[image: pipeline in java 11]

In order for me to get the job to reach the same throughput numbers, I have to specify the `--numberOfWorkerHarnessThreads=4` flag, and even then, throughput is still not 40/s like when I run the pipeline under Java 8.

[image: pipeline with java 11 and specify threads per worker]

What could be the difference between using Java 8 vs Java 11 for the pipeline? And why wouldn't the pipeline running under Java 11 automatically utilize the workers the same way as under Java 8?

I also tried recompiling and using Beam 2.26.0 for the Java 11 pipeline execution, but it had the same throughput.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/BEAM-10222) in Beam that makes the pipeline to default to only use 1 harness thread for Batch in Java 11. Specifying `numberOfWorkerHarnessThreads=4` makes the pipeline to use 4 harness would make it to use 4 thread.

You can see the workers did use around ~25% Cpu, which (since you were using a 4 core machine as *n1-highmem-4*, as it looks from the post), means 100%/4 cores = 25%.

Looking at the Jira, it should be fixed in 2.26.0, but maybe it was delayed to 2.27.0

Comment: Thank you, that seems to match exactly what I’ve been running into. I’ll try out 2.26.0 again and see what’s up.